# VBA - Split/Extract data into worksheet based on selected cell value with formattin

Tags: excel, vba

I have data (more than 60,000 records) in "Master" -sheet column A:Z. (Hidden Sheet)

And I have an another sheet "Form_Entry" which is visible and as some buttons. In Form_Entry sheet, cell E4 has drop-down (list of Master sheet column L unique values) of the **User Roles** list.

When user selects the role from the drop down (E4), and clicks the Create Button there I want to run this macro, which split all data of the particular role into new sheet with the same formatting as in Master, with name of that user role (E4.value). If users tries to Create Button for already selected user role then it won't allow to do so.

I tried the following code from extend office and it looks great,

```
Sub parse_data()
Dim lr As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim vcol, i As Integer
Dim icol As Long
Dim myarr As Variant
Dim title As String
Dim titlerow As Integer
vcol = 12       
Set ws = Sheets("Master sheet")       
lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
title = "A1:Z1"           
titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
icol = ws.Columns.Count
ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"
For i = 2 To lr
On Error Resume Next
If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
End If
Next
myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
ws.Columns(icol).Clear
For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
Else
Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
End If
ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
Next
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
ws.Activate
End Sub
```

But It split all the data into (all role) sheets (based on the role), But I want only one role which is selected by the users.

I tried change this piece of code but get error

```
ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"
```

instead of this I tried

```
Dim id As String
id = ActiveSheet.Range("C4").Value
 ws.Cells(1, icol) = id
```

Comment: you have an unclosed On Error Resume Next which is never a good idea as it hides any bugs that may be present.

Comment: Please INDENT your code...